# PostgreSQL - update table using select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

My question was to take the first letter of a survey responders first name and the first letter of the responders last name and concatenate the two so I get something along the lines of this: Sam Smith's would result in SS.

I'm using this query to do that and get the result I needed:

```
select concat(letterfirst, letterlast) as users
from (select substring(first_name,1,1) as letterfirst, 
             substring(last_name,1,1) as letterlast
       from survey_responders) as user1
```

Now I need to pass that result into the username column in the same table, survey_responders. I know I have to use a update statement but I can't seem to wrap my head around using a select statement with an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating the situation:

```
update survey_responders
    set username = concat(left(first_name, 1), left(last_name, 1));
```

Comment: You made that look way too easy. ugh! I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure that out. Thank you! :)